Unrecognized Data Type
I am follwoing the training in the (https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=deep+learning+with+keras+tensorflow+freecodecamp&&view=riverview&mmscn=mtsc&mid=5913353EA12EC6FE07BA5913353EA12EC6FE07BA&&aps=0&FORM=VMSOVR), the code line:
model.fit(x = scaled_train_samples, y =train_labels, batch_size = 10, epochs = 30, shuffle = True, verbose = 2)

produced the error:
ValueError: Unrecognized data type: x=MinMaxScaler() (of type <class 'sklearn.preprocessing._data.MinMaxScaler'>)

although both of the x and y are of np.ndarray data types.
any help here is much appreciated.

You need to include a reproducible example in the question itself, not as an external link.

Please add the necessary part of the code to debug. Where do you have x=MinMaxScaler() in your code ? that's not usual for a Scaler use.
